# Processing HTML form into function

Tags: php

I want to have a HTML form and then process it with php into function.

My index.php

```
<form action="process.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

My process.php

```
<?php
$number = htmlspecialchars($_GET["number"]);
$age = htmlspecialchars($_GET["age"]);

function Math ($number, $age) {
    $result = $number + $age;
    echo $result;
}

Math ();
?>
```

I can't work out why it doesn't work?

Comment: why do you use `htmlspecialchars` for input arguments? you need to use it only for output into html

Comment: I just started with PHP so not sure, i guess i saw someone doing it, anyway thanks for correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the parameters in the function call. Also you need to use `.` instead of `+` to concatenate.

```
<?php
$number = htmlspecialchars($_GET["number"]);
$age = htmlspecialchars($_GET["age"]);

function Math ($number, $age) {
    $result = $number . $age;
    echo $result;
}

Math ($number, $age);
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks it works, but one thing i dont understand is then why do i have to put 2 variables in function args if i have to specify them anyway later on when calling the function, if you know what i mean ;)

Comment: Considering the function is called `Math` and the two variables look like they're probably numbers, I think concatenation probably isn't the goal. (But then, the OP says it works, so I guess I shouldn't second-guess that.)

Comment: I wanted to add them actually

Answer (score 1):

You have not passed the parameter in function call:

```
Math($number,$age);
```

You need to check for isset else it ll give error when page load first time. Always try to return from function.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET["number"]) && isset($_GET["age"])) {

   $number = htmlspecialchars($_GET["number"]);
   $age = htmlspecialchars($_GET["age"]);

   function Math ($number, $age) {
     $result = $number + $age;
     return $result;
   }

   echo Math($number, $age);
 }
?>
```